# chrome.serial.connect callback scope issues

Tags: javascript, serial-port, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to communicate with a serial device in an chrome app. The issue i'm having is that the callbacks from the chrome.serial functions are in the wrong scope. everything is working if I put everything in the global scope but if I try to call anything in a "class" then nothing happens.

```
service = {};
service.state = "disconnected";
service.connect = function(){
    chrome.serial.connect(service.config.port, options, function (connectionInfo) {
        console.log("Connected"); // This works
        service.state = 'connected'; // This doesn't change the variable
        this.state = 'connected'; // This also doesn't change it
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where the 'state' variable is declared ?

Comment: Change the log to console.log("Connected", service) and post the results.

Comment: The returned value is the whole service object but not with the correct values, it returns the values for a new instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just bind the scope of your callback function to your service object.

```
service = {};
service.state = "disconnected";
service.connect = function() {
    chrome.serial.connect(this.config.port, options, function (connectionInfo) {
        console.log("Connected"); // This works
        this.state = 'connected';
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this by saving the scope in a local variable before this function call

```
service = {};
service.state = "disconnected";
service.connect = function(){
    var scope = this;
    chrome.serial.connect(service.config.port, options, function (connectionInfo) {
        console.log("Connected"); // This works
        service.state = 'connected'; // This doesn't change the variable
        this.state = 'connected'; // This also doesn't change it
        scope.state = 'connected'; // This works!
    }
}
```